# rabbitmq docker spring o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s)

Tags: spring, ssl, docker, rabbitmq

I have been trying to get send and receive messages on a rabbit MQ running in docker with ssl enabled.  I first got a Spring boot application working without ssl.  With everything running on localhost I succeeded in sending and receiving messages with the dockerized rabbit MQ.  But now, with the ssl auth plugin enabled in the dockerized rabbit MQ I get a strange message claiming

```
o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
```

When I look at the dockerized rabbit instance through the web console I see that there are no queues at all.  If I stop and restart the container I get the same result.

I have pointed rabbit MQ to this configuration as suggested by [Jeff Becker's blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/jeffreyabecker/Using-SSL-client-certificates-for-authentication-with-RabbitMQ)

The config file looks like this :

```
    %% -*- mode: erlang -*-
    [
     {rabbit,  [
        {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
        {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/home/callen/.ssh/private_key.pem"},
                  {certfile,"/home/callen/.ssh/private_key.pem"},
                  {keyfile,"/home/callen/.ssh/public_key.pem"},
                  {verify,verify_none},
                  {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
      ]}
    ].
```

Here is the stack trace from the Spring boot application :

```
2018-01-11 11:12:57.395  INFO 17786 --- [           main] n.k.r.r.RabbitConsumerApplicationTests   : Starting RabbitConsumerApplicationTests on localhost.localdomain with PID 17786 (started by callen in /home/callen/Projects/rabbit-consumer)
2018-01-11 11:12:57.396  INFO 17786 --- [           main] n.k.r.r.RabbitConsumerApplicationTests   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-01-11 11:12:57.482  INFO 17786 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@36b4fe2a: startup date [Thu Jan 11 11:12:57 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-01-11 11:12:58.351  INFO 17786 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3062a902] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-01-11 11:12:59.423  INFO 17786 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-01-11 11:12:59.529 ERROR 17786 --- [    container-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:368) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:573) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1430) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1387) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:336) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1171) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1422) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:147) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:153) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:285) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:909) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:799) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

What say you, good people?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I m facing same issue.

Comment: I was working a contract job at the time I reported this problem.  The job ended before I was able to find a solution and I have not pursued the solution after the conclusion of that contract.

Comment: Exact same problem